# how does mypy type checking work? -in vscode

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm hoping to get some clarification or a good starting point to learn about mypy, specifically around the idea of type checking within my code editor, vscode. I've installed mypy in the virtualenv I'm working in and successfully selected it as the linter under Python: Select Linter, Python: Run Linting. I do see some expected behaviors when testing snippets such as:

```
l: List[str] = [1, 'a', 'b']
```

where I have an error message prompting:
`List item 0 has incompatible type "int"; expected "A" mypy(error)`

I also tested something like:

```
class A: ...

l: List[A] = [42]
```

where I also get an expected error of `List item 0 has incompatible type "int"; expected "A" mypy(error)`

However when I'm working with objects defined outside the scope of my project, i.e external libs, I don't see the behavior I would expect:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

l: DataFrame = 42 # no error
```

I've seen similar issues, or lack of, with using other libs such as the Google Ads sdk and I'm not sure why or if I'm even getting the right picture here of how mypy works. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:

Per clarification from the comments, type stubs are necessary to enforce type checking, however, in the specific case of the `google-ads-python` client [library](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python), there are types available [here](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/tree/main/google/ads/googleads/v11/services/types)
that seem to fit this purpose. When testing an example:

```
from google.ads.googleads.v11.services.types.customizer_attribute_service import CustomizerAttributeOperation

l: List[CustomizerAttributeOperation] = [1, 2, 3] # no error
```

This will still not raise an error. Do type stubs require a particular format in order to be considered a type stub, e.g. the extension `.pyi`?

Comment: The library has to supply types, or you have to download them separately. Typing in Python is relatively new, and a lot of those libraries predate the feature.

Comment: If the external module doesn't have type stubs, then all of its types are considered `Any` and no type checking is performed on them.  I think there's a `pandas-types` module or similar that you can install to get some level of typechecking on `pandas`.

Comment: Note that there are options you can set on mypy (e.g. in `mypy.ini`) that cause it to flag missing type stubs as errors, which can help keep you from getting caught unawares by untyped modules (although then you're forced to go track down type stubs for all your modules, and if they don't have them you're stuck writing your own).

Comment: Thank you for the info everyone. I've updated the question with an example of a lib that seems to offer types, however mypy is still unable to detect a problem with mismatched type and assignment. Perhaps I should look more into type stubs, specifically how to create my own..

Comment: Maybe I'm saying something obvious, but if you're learning `mypy` - I'd suggest to abandon IDE integration, at least initially. Learn it from terminal to get feeling of its CLI and configuration (be it `mypy.ini` or `pyproject.toml`, doesn't really matter). When you understand how it is invoked and what external resources does it use, you may begin configuring your IDE to support mypy inline (although it is not necessary at all).

Comment: Regarding types source. You don't see any errors, because `google-ads-python` package is not typed, probably. Then every import from it is interpreted by `mypy` as `Any` - a type that is compatible with everything. To make use of types, external package needs stubs (package named `types-<package>` or `<package>-stubs`) or inline types (then it **must** contain empty file - "marker" - named `py.typed` in root folder).

Comment: For `pandas`, the stub package is named `pandas-stubs` ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs), pip-installable).